# A random variable constructed by sampling and maxing

Tags: order-statistics

Suppose I have a continuous random variable $X$.

Now I define a new random variable $Y$ by sampling $X$ $n$ times and then taking the max of the sample. Assume the samples are iit.

$$
Y = max(X_{1}, ... , X_{n}) $$

1. Is it possible to say something about $Y$ in terms of $X$, generally?
2. Suppose that $X$ is normal. Now what can I expect from $Y$?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/civil-and-environmental-engineering/1-151-probability-and-statistics-in-engineering-spring-2005/lecture-notes/app11_max.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express the CDF of $Y$ quite easily,

$$ F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \prod\limits_i^n\mathbb{P}(X_i \leq y) = (\mathbb{P}(X_i \leq y))^n$$

This is true because $max(X_1,..,X_n) \leq y \Longleftrightarrow X_i \leq y$ for all $i$.

Comment: That's so gorgeous. I should have worked on this one for longer, I feel like I could have discovered it. Thanks for the help.